# Why does word2vec outperform other neural network methods?

Tags: neural-network, word2vec, word-embedding

Why does word2vec outperform other neural network methods?

Word2vec is more shallow than other neural network methods(NNLM,RNNLM,etc.).

Can it be explained?

And I want to know whether it suffers any drawbacks because the word2vec model does not contain hidden layer (activation function like sigmoid, etc.)?

Comment: How do you compare  them (which measure)?

Comment: by accuracy measure?(in the 2013a word2vec paper)

Comment: You think that we all know that paper, the results and the methods you cite? It changes every 6 months (or even faster), 2013 is kinda old. I can find you 5 papers that beat word2vec on various metrics with different languages models. They all say that they are the best. If you have those kind of questions, cite your sources and explain better the context of your question :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood so far, the removal of the hidden layer does affect the accuracy. However, it results in a high computational gain that we can use the model to train on much bigger datasets than what was possible before. The main point of the model is that training a simple model on more data gives better results than more expensive models with smaller datasets.